# Open another tab from within Vim

Tags: vim, tabs

In Vim, if I wish to open another tab, I am currently write-quitting out of all of my documents, pressing up on the terminal and then adding the location of the new file I wish to open onto the end of the -p command. This is less than ideal.

What is the command to open a new tab from within Vim?

Comment: Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `:tabnew`.  Check the syntax on the link below for more info.

http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/442422-vim-tips-using-tabs

Comment: That works a treat, although you can't use the tab key to autocomplete the path which is a downer, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

My .vimrc for tab navigation:

```
nmap ,<C-t> :tabnew<cr>  
imap ,<C-t> <ESC>:tabnew<cr>  
map <C-J> :bnext<CR>  
map <C-K> :bprev<CR>  
map <C-L> :tabn<CR>  
map <C-H> :tabp<CR>
```